# Async Pipe Fails to Render Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

e(1): Updated code to address typo's in original question.
e(2): Attempted to 'JSON.stringify()' the data pushed into my JSON object in 'createContent()'.  No luck.
e(3): Added *plnkr* as requested: http://plnkr.co/edit/j024MYCQbypAGaf762fT

I have a model...

```
class Content {
  constructor(public name: string) { }
}
```

I have a service...

```
class ContentService {
  private _contents$: Subject<Content[]>
    = new Subject<Content[]>();

  get contents$(): Observable<Content[]> {
    return this._contents$.asObservable();
  }

  private _data: { contents: Content[] } = { contents: [] };

...

  load(): void {
    createContent(new Content("Test Content..."));
  }

  createContent(item: Content): void {
    this._data.contents.push(item);
    this._contents$.next(this._data.contents);
  }
}
```

I have a component...

```
@Component({
...
template: `
<h1 *ngFor="let item of contents$ | async">{{ item.name }}</h1>
`
})
class ContentListComponent {
  contents$: Observable<Content[]>;

  constructor(private _contentService: ContentService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contents$ = this._contentService.contents$;
    this._contentService.load();
  }
}
```

Simply put, I don't understand why the Observable in my component is not functioning correctly.

If I change these around, such that I have an array in the component, subscribe to the service 'contents$' to populate the array, then it's no biggie.

When I log the output of the service and functions called, everything is also dandy.  The only symptom I am experiencing is that the "*ngFor" does not appear to be properly handling the stream.  It's something obvious, isn't it?

Comment: I think this is the problem: `this.contents$ = this._contentService.contents$;`. Please try this in your template: `*ngFor="let item of _contentService.contents$ | async"`

Comment: Can you please try to move this line ` this.contents$ = this._contentService.contents$;` into the contructor? I haven't tried it but maybe the view doesn't like if `contents$` is `null` when it first tries to resolve the bindings.

Comment: @rinukkusu: The component's backing object has a property named 'contents$' as well.  That was my mistake naming these similarly for this question.  I did attempt it however, sourcing the service directly.  Nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Nice thought.  I moved it to the constructor, but the output is the same.  Still no dice.

Comment: A Plunker would be helpful

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I have had terrible luck getting Plunkr's to work for me from scratch.  Let me give it a whack though.

Comment: The `New` button in the Plunker editor provides a nice Angular 2.0 TS template for an easy start. The "live example" link at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html (below "Try it!") is slightly different but also a nice template to start with.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I have added the _plnkr_ to the original question.  Let me know if you are able to view it as it is my first one to share.

Comment: My next thought regards whether this is a topic of hot vs cold observables.  I sort of understand them, but I have not experienced handling them in too broad of a stroke.

Comment: Just saw your comment. Your suspicion is correct. See my answer. The Plunker was perfect btw :)

Comment: AHHHHH!! BEHAVIOR SUBJECT!! I even looked at this beast and wrote it off because I could not get a clear answer on when to use it.  I knew it was something silly.  Almost 4 hours of banging my head on the wall why this wouldn't fire off, haha.  Thanks!

Comment: Give me a moment to figure out how to mark your answer as the correct one.  I have only lurked around Stacked, never submitted, heh.

Comment: When using the Finnish notation, the dollar sign is read as a "s". So, it should be content$, not contents$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Angular evaluates the

```
<h1 *ngFor="let item of contents$ | async">{{ item.name }}</h1>
```

only when change detection runs the next time.

Because

```
this._service.load();
```

is executed sync, the event is emitted before Angular had a chance to subscribe.

If you for example use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject` which emits that last emitted value to new subscribers, then you get the desired behavior.

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dA3Weza9TSrjzYdAJQ9J?p=preview)

You could also invoke change detection manually before calling `this._service.load();` or call `this._service.load();` delayed
but that depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for this - I had no idea why BehaviorSubject was so important until now; just that I had a feeling it was a topic of hot vs cold.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I see a potential problem in your code:

```
createContent(item: Content): void {
  this._data.contents$.push(item);
  this._contents$.next(this._data.contents$);
}
```

I would use the following instead:

```
createContent(item: Content): void {
  this._data.contents.push(item); // <----
  this._contents$.next(this._data.contents); // <----
}
```

Comment: Too many "contents/$", heh.  Apologies though, this was just a typo in the original question.  I have updated it to reflect the code I have.